# What kind of relay do I need?

Tags: transistors, relay

I have some remotely controlled sockets and I would like to rip open the remote control (3v DC) and connect it to the rooms lighting switch (240V AC) so the sockets are triggered when the light is switched on.
Any idea what type of relay I would need to do this (240v trigger with a 3v load) ? Would it be small enough to conceal in the backbox of a light switch?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to control your rooms lighting using a remote control? then Is the socket directly controlled by the remote control?

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3V to drive the relay, then you can possibly use a [Solid State Relay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/24V-380V-40A-250V-SSR-40-DA-Solid-State-Relay-Module-3-32V-DC-To-AC-/201414937205). It seems to be just barely enough to turn it on.

However I feel that if you are asking this kind of question, you shouldn't be modifying the AC wiring in your home just yet. It could possibly kill you and others either by electrical shock or fire.

Please be careful and research a bit more, possibly for [other](https://learn.adafruit.com/reverse-engineering-a-bluetooth-low-energy-light-bulb/overview) kinds of controllable lights which you can also modify and hack.

Comment: It's the other way around. I want the mains to switch the 3V circuit.

Comment: Have you considered using a 3V PSU? Whenever the 240VAC is on there is 3V in its output

Comment: Perhaps something like this ?http://m.ebay.co.uk/itm/VTX-214-003-105-VIGORTRONIX-AC-DC-CONV-FIXED-1-O-P-3W-5V-/351234577661

Comment: what is the 3V load you want turned on?

Answer (score 0):

I used a zero cross - Triac output optoisolator : MOC43043 and isolated tape Triac : TBA06 for 6A , TBA08 for 8A, TBA10 for 10A ... [image]